# How to get back my "Run with PowerShell" context menu item after installing/configuring VS Code?

Tags: powershell, context-menu, visual-studio-code

I installed VSCode and the PowerShell extension, and I used the File Explorer property sheet to set VSCode as the default editor for `.ps1` files. Unfortunately, however, doing so removed the context menu item `Run with PowerShell`. I don't seem to be able to get it back.

My registry settings are intact—according to [this blog post](https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/whats-behind-run-with-powershell-context-menu/)—but the problem persists.

[image]
[image]

I tried setting PowerShell itself as the default editor, but that results in the ability to run a script by double-clicking it. That feels a bit unsafe to me, so I'd rather not have that arrangement.

I've found plenty of tips on how to do it for running a script with admin permissions, but I don't need that.

How can I restore the context menu to its pre-VSCode state, i.e. enabling me to run a script by right-clicking it and selecting `Run with PowerShell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing VSCode, should have not removed your PowerShell shortcut. I have it on all my Dev boxes and it was not changed, both are there, but VSC, is set as 'Open With Code', not 'Run with code'

Anyway, a workaround is to just copy and paste the PowerShell shortcut to your SendTo folder, [image]

then just select right click > SendTo and select your PowerShell shortcut.

You can add any shortcut you want in the SendTo folder and it just shows up in your SendTo menu.

I have lots there personally, as shown above, specifically for this reason, or just use the 'Open With' context menu.

[image]

As for this...

> I tried setting PowerShell itself as the default editor, but that
>   results in the ability to run a script by double-clicking it. That
>   feels a bit unsafe to me, so I'd rather not have that arrangement.

… yeppers, don't do that.

***Update for OP***

As for this ...

> I don't believe the menu item left as a result of installing VSCode. I
>   think it left after I changed Open with from ISE to VSCode.

... Ditch any modification to the 'Open With' item and set it back to the default of Notepad. This will bring back the 'Run with PowerShell' context menu item.

Comment: Now that I think about it, and after you mention it, I don't believe the menu item left as a result of installing VSCode. I think it left after I changed `Open with` from ISE to VSCode. Thanks for the workaround idea; I'd like to hold off a bit on accepting it, however, in hopes of finding a way to get it back on the top level of the context menu instead of nested a level down.

Comment: See my update for you.

Comment: That's it! Good job *:-)*

Comment: No worries. Glad things got back for you. The only other option would have been doing a system reset back to a date where all things were normal.

Comment: Ikkers. I never did like those things.

Comment: I feel U, as they get corrupted, and just disappear. ;-} Especially, well, several times after Windows Updates, especially CU's.